# How to show property of person object on html div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop, object

```js
function person(name, age, dob, gender, id) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.dob = new Date(dob);
  this.gender = gender;
  this.id = id;
}

// Declaring Variables.
let person1 = new person('John Doe', 19, '19-02-2001', 'male', '001');
let person2 = new person('Jane Doe', 19, '22-02-2001', 'female', '002');
let input = document.getElementById('text');
let show = document.getElementById('result');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

// creating function to run code 

button.onclick = function() {
  if (input === person1.id) {
    show.innerHTML = `Name : ${person1.name} <br> Age : ${person1.age} <br> DOB : ${person1.dob} <br> Gender : ${person1.gender}`;
  } else if (input === person2.id) {
    show.innerHTML = `Name : ${person2.name} <br> Age : ${person2.age} <br> DOB : ${person2.dob} <br> Gender : ${person2.gender}`;
  } else {
    show.innerHTML = 'Software Crashed!';
    console.log(input.value);
    console.log(person1.id);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

#clear {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 60%;
}

#text {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 70%;
}

#button {
  padding: 7px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

#result {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clear">
</div>
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name For Details" id="text" required>
  <button id="button">Submit</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

I'm trying to print the property of the person on the html div tag named as result but it shows software crashed as I have put in the else statement in javascript. On console logging both the input id is matching with the person.id but still it is showing only else statement. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: You mean like this?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/rNVqRJe

Comment: Yes ! It work's ! What did you change ?

Comment: I have changed ```input``` to ```input.value``` in if statement.. If this works shall I post it as answer?? Can you verify it??

Comment: Yes it's working. Thanks ! But dob is showing invalid. Is there a fix for that too ?

Comment: Will check and post..

Comment: Use Date in this format. 'YYYY-MM-DD' and it works ! Thanks friend for your help

Comment: Posted as answer, feel free to accept the solution if it resolves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line, `if (input === person1.id) { .. }`  you are trying to compare the input element with id, instead of value of input. Hence

Change

```
input === person1.id
```

to

```
input.value === person1.id
```

```js
function person(name, age, dob, gender, id) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.dob = new Date(dob);
  this.gender = gender;
  this.id = id;
}

// Declaring Variables.
let person1 = new person('John Doe', 19, '2001-02-19', 'male', '001');
let person2 = new person('Jane Doe', 19, '2001-02-22', 'female', '002');
let input = document.getElementById('text');
let show = document.getElementById('result');
let button = document.getElementById('button');

// creating function to run code 

button.onclick = function() {
  if (input.value === person1.id) {
    show.innerHTML = `Name : ${person1.name} <br> Age : ${person1.age} <br> DOB : ${person1.dob} <br> Gender : ${person1.gender}`;
  } else if (input === person2.id) {
    show.innerHTML = `Name : ${person2.name} <br> Age : ${person2.age} <br> DOB : ${person2.dob} <br> Gender : ${person2.gender}`;
  } else {
    show.innerHTML = 'Software Crashed!';
    console.log(input.value);
    console.log(person1.id);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

#clear {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 60%;
}

#text {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 70%;
}

#button {
  padding: 7px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

#result {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clear">
</div>
<div id="input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name For Details" id="text" required>
  <button id="button">Submit</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

To get the right date, as like you mentioned in comments, you could change the format,

```
'DD-MM-YYYY'
19-02-2001
```

to

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
2001-02-19
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check input value (not input itself) with objects.
so change you *button.onclick* funcntion to this will solve your problem:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  if (input.value === person1.id) {
    show.innerHTML = `Name : ${person1.name} <br> Age : ${person1.age} <br> DOB : ${person1.dob} <br> Gender : ${person1.gender}`;
  } else if (input.value === person2.id) {
    show.innerHTML = `Name : ${person2.name} <br> Age : ${person2.age} <br> DOB : ${person2.dob} <br> Gender : ${person2.gender}`;
  } else {
    show.innerHTML = 'Software Crashed!';
    console.log(input.value);
    console.log(person1.id);
  }
}
```